# Is it possible to use Bitmap as the data source of ILNumerics ILPanel?

Tags: bitmap, ilnumerics

1) Is it possible to use Bitmap as the data source of ILNumerics ILPanel?
2) How to make the axis of ILNumerics ILPanel invisible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Convert the bitmap data to an 'ILArray' and use that for plotting the common way.

ILPanel does not have axes. You probably mean ILPlotCube? You can control the axes via the ILPlotCube.Axes property.

The line properties for the edges of the plot cube are controlled by the `ILPlotCube.Lines` property.

Link to the class API reference docu for the ILPlotCube class: 
http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_ILNumerics_Drawing_Plotting_ILPlotCube.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I tried plotcube.Axes.Visible = false; The xyz axis were invisible, but the frame is still visible. Is it also possible to let the frame invisible? Thank you.

Comment: You may also consider using your objects without any plot cube? If you do not need plot cube functionality, you can simply add any object to ilPanel1.Scene.Camera...